# #VALUE! error when using SUMPRODUCT in excel 2010 and 2013

Tags: excel, sum, product

I have a cell that checks whether or not a group of cells are within a certain date range, and if they are, to count them (I need it to work with excel 2003 so I used SUMPRODUCT instead of COUNTIFS). When I open it in excel 2016 I have no issues, and when I save as a *.xls file I have no issue. But when it's opened in 2010 or 2013 it comes up with a #VALUE! Error. Any ideas?

Picture of specific cell formula is in:
[image]

Ps: Cell B6 in reference contains a date, so it will only show the value if it's past the current date
Thanks!

UPDATE: I managed to find a computer with excel 2013, in the 'show calculation steps' window I can see that the error results in the evaluation of 'Jog Log'!$M$500 <= DATEVALUE("9/30/2016")

Comment: =IF(TODAY()>=B6,SUMPRODUCT(--('Job Log'!$M$7:$M$500>=DATEVALUE("9/1/2016")),--('Job Log'!$M$7:$M$500<=DATEVALUE("9/30/2016"))),"")

Comment: My guess is that you have an error or text in the `'Job Log'!$M$7:$M$500` range.  Check the range to ensure that the values are in fact true dates and not text that look like dates.

Comment: I checked and im all good for that. The only thing is that some fields in the range are blank. Given that it runs without issue in excel 2016, could that be an issue in earlier versions of excel?

Answer (score 0):

In excel 2013 DATEVALUE apparently doesn't allow dates to be entered in the form "9/1/2016" Once all dates were entered in an alternate format "1 September 2016" all #VALUE! errors went away.